# Integrate a simple separable equation $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\frac{2}{y^3}=0$

Tags: integration

**Background**: this is from Bence, Hobson, Riley describing how as an extension to the method of isobaric equations where instead of assigning y and dy a weight of m, and x and dx a weight of 1 to determine if each term is dimensionally consistent for a substition of $y=vx^m$ followed by $x=e^t$, you can also look just at x and dx or y and dy to see if a substition of $x=e^t$ or $y=e^v$ will work.

**question**: Simplifying $x^2 y''+xy'+\frac{2}{y^3}=0$ yields with $x=e^t$ : 
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\frac{2}{y^3}=0\tag{1}$$
According to the text, direct integration of (1) yields: $\frac{dy}{dt}=\sqrt{2(c_1+1/y^2)}$
How was this "direct" integration carried out? What is it with respect to?

Comment: $$2y''y'+4y'y^{-3}=2y'(y''+2y^{-3})=0=((y')^2-2y^{-2})'$$